# Creating a csv file from python readlines()

Tags: python-3.x, csv, readlines

I want to create a CSV file from a text file

**text_file.txt**

```
Friday,09071235462,08:42:48

Princely,08123456,08:46:45
```

My code to convert the file

```
#Convert to csv
import csv
for_csv_list = []
with open(f'./text_file.txt', "r") as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        if line != "\n":
            for_csv_list.append(line.strip().split())


with open("the_csv_file.csv","w") as convert_to_csv:
    writer = csv.writer(convert_to_csv)
    writer.writerows(for_csv_list)
```

Then I tried to open my converted CSV file

```
f = open("the_csv_file.csv")
csv_f = csv.reader(f)
for row in csv_f:
    print("this is row = ",row)
f.close()
```

The code returned

```
this is row =  ['Friday,09071235462,08:42:48']
this is row =  []
this is row =  ['Princely,08123456,08:46:45']
this is row =  []
```

Please how will I remove the empty list since my expected result should be:

```
this is row =  ['Friday,09071235462,08:42:48']
this is row =  ['Princely,08123456,08:46:45']
```

Comment: It seems like you just want to remove blank lines. Would `grep -v '^$' text_file.txt` meet your need?